# Stably equivalent but not homotopy equivalent

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

What are some examples of (compact, say) manifolds $X$ and $Y$ that are stably equivalent, i.e. $\Sigma^{\infty}X_+\simeq\Sigma^{\infty}Y_+$, but are not homotopy equivalent?

Comment: Any pair of homology spheres of the same dimension. After one stabilization they are equivalent by Whitehead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe it is worth adding some simply-connected examples.

Every simply connected closed 4-manifold may be described as $X = D^4 \cup_f (S^2 \vee \cdots \vee S^2)$, where $f$ is a map $S^3 \to S^2 \vee \cdots \vee S^2$; $\pi_3$ of this wedge is known to be generated by Hopf maps and Whitehead products of two factors, so we may represent such a map by a symmetric integer matrix $A$; this integer matrix may just as well be interpreted as the cup product pairing $H^2(X;\Bbb Z) \otimes H^2(X;\Bbb Z) \to H^4(X;\Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z$. The resulting homotopy type is determined up to isomorphism by $A$ up to isomorphism of symmetric bilinear forms over $\Bbb Z$. See, for instance, Example 4.52 in Hatcher's algebraic topology book.

On the other hand, if $n > 2$, then $$\pi_{n+1}(\vee^k S^n) = (\pi_{n+1} S^n)^k = (\Bbb Z/2)^k.$$ The Whitehead product factors vanish. This follows by an inductive argument using the Hilton-Milnor theorem, as stated [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1661390/98602).

Furthermore, any map in $GL_k(\Bbb Z)$ may be realized as an automorphism of $H_n(\vee^k S^n)$ by some autoequivalence of $\vee^k S^n$, and the map $GL_k(\Bbb Z) \to GL_k(\Bbb Z/2)$ is surjective (check at the level of the generating set of elementary matrices). Because every two nonzero vectors in $(\Bbb Z/2)^k$ are related by some matrix in $GL_k(\Bbb Z/2)$, the homotopy type of $D^{n+2} \cup_f (\vee^k S^n)$ is determined entirely by whether or not $f$ is nontrivial.

Suspending the presentation given for $X$ takes the diagonals of the matrix $A$ mod 2, and so the homotopy type of the suspension is dictated by whether or not $X$ was spin (that is, whether or not its intersection form was even). If $X$ was spin, then $$\Sigma X \simeq S^5 \vee^{b_2} S^3;$$ if $X$ was not spin, then $$\Sigma X \simeq \Sigma \Bbb{CP}^2 \vee^{b_2-1} S^3.$$ In particular, the stable homotopy type is determined entirely by "even-ness" and rank of the intersection form.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this gives examples of manifolds that are stably equivalent but have different cup product structures. Doesn't an equivalence of the spectra imply an isomorphism of the cohomology rings?

Comment: @user131711 No. In fact, the cup product is destroyed after one stabilization: $\tilde H^*(\Sigma X)$ has trivial cup products. (This is a straightforward exercise using the relative cup product and the fact that $\Sigma X$ has a cover by two contractible pieces.) All that lives is the Steenrod algebra action. This is visible at the level of spectra: $H^*(X; \Bbb Z/2) = [\Sigma^\infty X, H\Bbb Z/2]$, and the Steenrod algebra is $[H\Bbb Z/2, H\Bbb Z/2]$, which acts by postcomposition.

Comment: The Steenrod algebra action is how one checks that $\Sigma \Bbb{CP}^2$ and $S^5$ are not stably equivalent.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the cup product on $\Sigma X_+$ is given using the diagonal $\Sigma^{\infty}(\Sigma X_+)\rightarrow\Sigma^{\infty}(\Sigma X_+)\wedge \Sigma^{\infty}(\Sigma X_+)$. Since $S^1\rightarrow S^1\wedge S^1$ is nullhomotopic, there is no cup product. On the other hand, the cup product on $X$ is induced by compositions $\Sigma^{\infty}X_+\rightarrow\Sigma^{\infty}X_+\wedge\Sigma^{\infty}X_+\rightarrow HR\wedge HR\rightarrow HR$. Shouldn't an equivalence of the spectra give an identification of the diagonal maps, and so the same cup products?

Comment: @user131711 Clearly there must be an error by the simple fact that if $\Sigma X \sim \Sigma Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are stable homotopy equivalent (by definition), and as above you may kill the cup product. In particular, suspending $D^4 \cup_{2 \in \pi_3 S^2} S^2$ you get $S^5 \vee S^3$. I think the error is this: The definition of the first diagonal map relies on the space $X$ as opposed to its stable homotopy type; suspension spectra have diagonal maps but that structure depends on $X$. You have therefore defined the cohomology ring of a space. (Spectra do not have natural diagonals.)

Comment: In general, when one says that $E$ is a multiplicative cohomology theory, that means that $E^*(X)$ is a ring for $X$ a space, not for $X$ a spectrum. For $X$ a spectrum we have that $E^*(X)$ is an $E^*E$-module.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest examples are given by complements of open neighborhoods of distinct knots in $S^n$.

More generally, Spanier-Whitehead duality says that if $X$ is a compact simplicial complex and if $f,g:X \rightarrow S^n$ are embeddings, then $S^n - Im(f)$ is stabily equivalent to $S^n - Im(g)$.

See my notes [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SpanierWhitehead.pdf) for an elementary discussion.

Comment: [Dold, Albrecht,  A simple proof of the Jordan-Alexander complement theorem.
Amer. Math. Monthly 100 (1993), no. 9, 856–857] has a six line elementary (but sneaky) proof that if A, a closed subset of R^m is homeomorphic to B, a closed subset of R^n, then the complement of A x 0 in R^{m+n} is homeomorphic to the complement of 0 x B is R^{m+n}.

Comment: @NicholasKuhn: Wow, that's a really beautiful proof!  Thanks for sharing it.